# How can I break the while loop when data in the input file exhaust?

Tags: c++, input, file-io

I'm reading data from a text file. How can I break the `while` loop as soon as the data in the file exhausts? In an ideal condition this situation should occur much before the var `i` attains the value of `max`.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#define max 20

int main()
{
    string arr[max][4];
    int i=0, j;
    while(i<max)
    {
        for(j=0; j<4; j++)
        {
            cin>>arr[i][j];
            if(j==2)
                arr[i][1] = arr[i][1]+arr[i][2];
        }
        i = i+1;
        
        //cout<<"\n";   
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The contents of the file:

```
15101049 PRIYESH DAMOR p.damor
15101061 SIMRAN SONI simran.soni
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to check wether the result of the operation

```
cin >> arr[i][j]
```

is successful or not? When the end of the file is reached it is supposed to be in a failed state. By checking this you should be able to break out of the loop.

Comment: I've tried with
if(!cin>>arr[i][j])
     break;

It didn't work.

Comment: try using it like this:
        if (!(cin >> arr[i][j]))

Comment: Your piece of code evaluates first cin, it is equivalent to typing:
        ((!cin) >> arr[i][j])
thats the reason the comparison was not working.